# Django Registration with Django cms

Tags: django, django-cms, django-registration

I have integrated django-registration with django-cms. I have multilingual django-cms for my site with two languages English and french. I am facing issue in url-mapping. as django-cms has multiple language, so it attached language code after domain name. While in django-registration it consider such url as 404. 
Below is flow, I putted registration button on click of that I have explicitly set to `http://localhost:8000/accounts/register/` and it display registration page properly, but after successful completion of registration, it redirects to `http://localhost:8000/en/accounts/register/complete/` , where language code is attached with url and django-registration says page not found. If I manually remove language code from url, it works fine.

Can anybody help me ?

url.py for project.

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^', include('cms.urls'), name="home"),
   url(r'^news/', include('multilingual_news.urls')),
   url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
   url(r'^member/',include('openerp_member.urls')),
   (r'^accounts/',include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
)
```

Comment: cleanup your urls, cms rule should be last one, to avoid matching news/search/member/accounts

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an AppHook for Django-Registration. So what I did was:

- create a new app called "cmsauth"
- create the according `cms_apps.py`:

  ```
  from cms.app_base import CMSApp
  from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
  from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

  class RegistrationApphook(CMSApp):
      name = _("RegistrationApphook")
      urls = ["registration.backends.hmac.urls"]

  apphook_pool.register(RegistrationApphook)
  ```
- create a CMS Page like "Accounts"
- link the AppHook `RegistrationApphook` (you might need to restart server for it to become available)

Now you should be able to reach the URLs.